# CSS Margin is showing on different places between browsers

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a simple object that I would like display at a certain location of my page.

Code:

```
.DownloadBtn
{
    height:35px; 
    width:150px; 
    background:#09F; 
    display:block; 
    position:absolute; 
    margin:280px 60px;
}

<a href="/products.html" class="DownloadBtn">Download Now</a>
```

This displays my download button at the perfect location on Firefox. 
However, on Google Chrome, it slides more on the left side.
on IE, it slides even more on the left side.

so basically, it's kind of like this:

Firefox: --------DownloadNow--------

Chrome: ----DownloadNow-----------

IE: --DownloadNow-------------------

Is there a way I can have it at a sec location for all browsers?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: It stays in the same position on all of those browsers on my computer.

Comment: negative: care to explain? hmm... it's not on mine for some reason..

Comment: Which version of IE? How many pixels in each case? Screenshot? Fiddle reproducing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can load IE specific stylesheets using

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I am talking about IE8+, I don't think they would require IE specific stylesheets. That still does not fix the chrome issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this in CSS

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the valid way, but I've fixed it using the margin: auto property.
See the code below for my example.

```
.downloadbtn
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    right: 400px;
    top: 200px;
}
```